# Does partial instanc-hour appear frequently in EC2 on-demand instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Because pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour.

Here is my question:

Does the **partial instance-hour** appear **frequently** or **rarely**?

Or in what kind of context, the **partial instance-hour** appear **frequently**?

Would anyone has these experiences on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial hours happen most frequently when using systems that scale often. For example, in my system I launch 10-20 servers extra each saturday and sunday to handle the extra traffic. When these servers are stopped I will be charged a partial hour. Amazon has a new feature for auto scaling groups that tells it to terminate ( if it has to ) the servers closer to the hour marker in order to save money.

Other possible uses are for services like MapReduce where a large number of instances will be started and then when the job is complete they will be terminated.

My experiences though is that the actual cost of partial hours is insignificant for me. Maybe if you're using larger servers it costs a lot but i'm using the c1.medium and i barely notice the $5 i get charged on a weekend for partial hours.

Comment: You are right,but if you consider that your peak time is very short and not predicted.10 minutes every time causes your 6x cost.

Comment: Thanks to your valuable answer.What I said just now is only a rare example.